# Cassandra cluster with bad insert performance and insert stability

Tags: java, database, cassandra, key-value, datastax-java-driver

I have to store around 250 numerical values per second, per client, which is around 900k numbers per hour. It probably will not be a full-day recording (probably between 5-10 hours a day), but I will partition my data based on the client id and the day the reading is made. The maximum row length comes at about 22-23M which is still manageable. Neverteless, my scheme looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE measurement (
  clientid text,
  date text,
  event_time timestamp,
  value int,
  PRIMARY KEY ((clientid,date), event_time)
);
```

The keyspace has a replication factor of 2, just for testing, the snitch is `GossipingPropertyFileSnitch` and `NetworkTopologyStrategy`. I know that replication factor 3 is more production standard.

Next up, I created a small cluster on the companies servers, three bare metal virtualized machines with 2 CPUs x 2 cores and 16GB of RAM and a lot of space. I'm in gigabit LAN with them. The cluster is operational, based on the nodetool.

Here is the code I'm using to test my setup:

```
        Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
                .addContactPoint("192.168.1.100")
                .addContactPoint("192.168.1.102")
                .build();
        Session session = cluster.connect();
        DateTime time = DateTime.now();
        BlockingQueue<BatchStatement> queryQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue(50, true);

    try {

        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(15); //changed the pool size also to throttle inserts

        String insertQuery = "insert into keyspace.measurement (clientid,date,event_time,value) values (?, ?, ?, ?)";
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = session.prepare(insertQuery);
        BatchStatement batch = new BatchStatement(BatchStatement.Type.LOGGED); //tried with unlogged also

        //generating the entries
        for (int i = 0; i < 900000; i++) { //900000 entries is an hour worth of measurements
            time = time.plus(4); //4ms between each entry
            BoundStatement bound = preparedStatement.bind("1", "2014-01-01", time.toDate(), 1); //value not important
            batch.add(bound);

            //The batch statement must have 65535 statements at most
            if (batch.size() >= 65534) {
                queryQueue.put(batch);
                batch = new BatchStatement();
            }
        }
        queryQueue.put(batch); //the last batch, perhaps shorter than 65535

        //storing the data
        System.out.println("Starting storing");
        while (!queryQueue.isEmpty()) {
            pool.execute(() -> {
                try {

                    long threadId = Thread.currentThread().getId();
                    System.out.println("Started: " + threadId);
                    BatchStatement statement = queryQueue.take();
                    long start2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    session.execute(statement);
                    System.out.println("Finished " + threadId + ": " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start2));
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex.toString());
                }
            });

        }
        pool.shutdown();
        pool.awaitTermination(120,TimeUnit.SECONDS);


    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
    } finally {
        session.close();
        cluster.close();
    }
```

I came up with the code by reading posts here and on other blogs and websites. As I understood it is important for the client to use multiple threads, that's why I have done this. I also tried using async operations.

The bottom line result is this, no matter which approach I use, one batch executes in 5-6 seconds, although it might take up to 10. It takes the same if I enter just one batch (so, only ~65k columns) or if I use a dumb single thread application. Honestly, I expected a bit more. Especially since I get more or less similar performance on my laptop with a local instance.

The second, maybe more important issue, are the exceptions I am facing in an unpredictable manner. These two:

> com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.WriteTimeoutException: Cassandra
>   timeout during write query at consistency ONE (1 replica were required
>   but only 0 acknowledged the write)

and

> com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All
>   host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /192.168.1.102:9042
>   (com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/192.168.1.102:9042]
>   Connection has been closed), /192.168.1.100:9042
>   (com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/192.168.1.100:9042]
>   Connection has been closed), /192.168.1.101:9042
>   (com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/192.168.1.101:9042]
>   Connection has been closed))

In the bottom line, am I doing something wrong? Should I reorganize the way I load data, or change the scheme. I tried reducing the row length (so I have 12-hour rows) but that didn't make a big difference.

==============================
Update:

I was rude and forgot to paste an example of the code I used after the question was answered. It works reasonably well, however I'm continuing my research with KairosDB and binary transfer with Astyanax. It looks like I can get much better performance with them over CQL, although KairosDB can have some issues when it is in overload (but I'm working on it) and Astyanax is a bit verbose to use for my taste. Nevertheless, here is the code, I'm maybe mistaken somewhere.

The semaphore slot number has no effect on performance when going above 5000, its almost constant.

```
String insertQuery = "insert into keyspace.measurement     (userid,time_by_hour,time,value) values (?, ?, ?, ?)";
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement =     session.prepare(insertQuery);
        Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(15000);

    System.out.println("Starting " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    DateTime time = DateTime.parse("2015-01-05T12:00:00");
    //generating the entries
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for (int i = 0; i < 900000; i++) { 

        BoundStatement statement = preparedStatement.bind("User1", "2015-01-05:" + time.hourOfDay().get(), time.toDate(), 500); //value not important
        semaphore.acquire();
        ResultSetFuture resultSetFuture = session.executeAsync(statement);
        Futures.addCallback(resultSetFuture, new FutureCallback<ResultSet>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(@Nullable com.datastax.driver.core.ResultSet resultSet) {

                semaphore.release();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
                System.out.println("Error: " + throwable.toString());
                semaphore.release();
            }
        });
        time = time.plus(4); //4ms between each entry
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What are your results using unlogged batching? Are you sure you want to use batch statements at all? 
https://medium.com/@foundev/cassandra-batch-loading-without-the-batch-keyword-40f00e35e23e

Comment: Not drastically different. I'm pretty sure I want to use batch, because I already worked on similar things in other projects, and statements one-by-one usually were slower. It does not make sense for it to be faster, anyway.

Comment: Spod is right. Batches in Cassandra are not a performance optimization. Logged batches should only be used if atomicity is required and there is a performance penalty to achieve atomic writes. Even unlogged batches are often slower than straight async queries, they essentially force unnecessary coordination (unless you're batching by key and using token aware--maybe you are here). I tend to recommend straight async writes anyway. Here's another article to back this view:http://lostechies.com/ryansvihla/2014/08/28/cassandra-batch-loading-without-the-batch-keyword/

Comment: Regarding your timeouts, this will happen once you start to overwhelm your c* nodes with too many writes. It's easy to do this with async queries as your program is generating writes as fast as it can nonstop. After removing your batches (especially logging) you should see an improvement but you may have to throttle your writes or even increase your timeouts if your SLA's permits.

Comment: Ok, that is interesting. I thought that batching reduces the network overhead. Is there any special technique I could use to throttle? I was thinking about a Semaphore. That probably means I should manually tweak the number of parallel async writes. 
What are the figures I should aim for and call good?
I think increasing the timeout is ok. There will probably be an intermediate step between the server receiving the data and it being loaded to the database (a simple file cache, or something like that, maybe).

Comment: To summarize, you were right. The alleged network overhead (if any?) is no reason to use batch statements. I've fallen back to a simpler solution with async operations, and hit the numbers from the benchmarks, around 30k ops on a 3-node cluster. I've used a semaphore for congestion control, and I could easily crank it up to 10000 slots, but I've noticed that the performance cap is much lower (but it is still stable). I did not touch the timeouts. Also, make sure you have a reliable wired connection to the servers! Before all of this i was in WiFi, wansn't fun. Thanks very much to both of you.

Comment: @AleksandarStojadinovic please show the sample of your code for insert - I have the same problem

Comment: @sedovav, I've added the code, try it out. Ofcourse, everyone else is invited to take a look, I maybe missing something out.

Comment: thank you @AleksandarStojadinovic! But i've never been able to get rid of this exception using the same approach with semaphore.  I alwais get com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /172.26.30.96 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.DriverException: Timeout during read), /172.26.30.36 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.DriverException: Timeout during read)) after inserting several thouthands of rows.

Comment: @sedovav try to reduce the semaphore value to 1 and see if the problem still remains. Afterwards you could try to increase it step by step.

Comment: @AleksandarStojadinovic i've tried it until "GC overhead limit exceeded". I think the "DriverException: Timeout during read" is somehow connected with Cassandra.yaml settings...

Comment: If it failed with the semaphor size = 1, like Stefan said, than you have some other issue. The only time I had GC overhead limit exceeded is when I used the sync execution and really went mad with the insert size.