# Cassandra PreparedStatement vs normal insert

Tags: cassandra, prepared-statement, cql

I'm using Cassandra for my project and I was facing a timeout issue during writes, the same the guy was receiving in this post [Cassandra cluster with bad insert performance and insert stability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27902232/cassandra-cluster-with-bad-insert-performance-and-insert-stability) (at the moment I'm testing with only one node, Java Driver, last release of Cassandra). The application has to insert a huge quantity of data per user once per day (during nights). I have a rest controller that accepts files and then processes them as they arrive in parallel to insert values in Cassandra. I have to insert 1million entries per user, where an entry has up to 8 values (time is not so important, it can take also 10minutes). Following the answer provided in [Cassandra cluster with bad insert performance and insert stability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27902232/cassandra-cluster-with-bad-insert-performance-and-insert-stability) I decided to add executeAsync(), Semaphore and PreparedStatement to my application, while previously I was using none of them.

The problem now is that, using variable keyspaces (one per user) and having the necessity to update lists in the database, I can't initialize my PreparedStatements in the initialization phase but I have to do it at least once per file processed (one file contains 10+k entries) and an user has to upload up to 100 files per day. For this reason, I'm getting this warning:

```
Re-preparing already prepared query INSERT INTO c2bdd9f7073dce28ed973238ac85b6e5d6162fce.sensorMonitoringLog (timestamp, sensorId, isLogging) VALUES (?, ?, ?). Please note that preparing the same query more than once is generally an anti-pattern and will likely affect performance. Consider preparing the statement only once.
```

My question is: is it a good practice to use PreparedStatement like this or it is better to use normal insert with executeAsync()?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing a timeout issue during write, it is a good idea to use PreparedStatement but not to use asynchronous insert. Timeouts are a way to prevent Cassandra from work overload. With asynchronism you are giving it more work at the same time and the risk of OOM would grow.

To do things properly with PreparedStatement, you have to create one and only one Session object by keyspace. Then each session must prepare its own statement once.

Moreover, be aware their is a thread safety risk with PreparedStatement and asynchronism. Preparing a statement must be synchronized. But once again, I advice you not to use ExecuteAsynch in such case.