# Inserting Into Cassandra using batch statements

Tags: java, datastax, cqlsh, cassandra-2.1

I am inserting data into Cassandra coming from a csv file using batch statements. My table looks like this
create table exposures(expoid bigint,fileid bigint,studyid text, projname text, w text, x text, y text, z text)

```
System.out.println(colDataMap);

String  keyspace = "orchtablespaces";
String tabName = fileName;
//String tableFile = "/home/blr-lt-202/empAccount.txt";
String tableFile = fname;

Set<String> colNamesSet = colDataMap.keySet();
String[] colNames = colNamesSet.toArray(new String[colNamesSet.size()]);
System.out.println("ColNames ::" +colNames);

String makeStatement =  makeSt(keyspace,tabName,colNames);

System.out.println("makeStatement ::"+makeStatement);

if(count==65534)
{
    session.executeAsync(bs);
    count = 0;
    bs = new BatchStatement();
}

PreparedStatement statement = session.prepare(makeStatement);
//bcz expo id and seq_n
String expoid =(String) colDataMap.get("expoid");
String Seq_No = (String) colDataMap.get("Seq_No");
colDataMap.put(expoid, Long.valueOf(expoid));
colDataMap.put("Seq_No", Long.valueOf(Seq_No));

BoundStatement query = statement.bind(colDataMap.values().toArray(new Object[colDataMap.size()]));

//BoundStatement query = statement.bind(colDataMap.get("Seq_No"),colDataMap.get("fileId"),colDataMap.get("studyId"),colDataMap.get("projectName"),colDataMap.get("dosetxt"),colDataMap.get("sdurtunit"),colDataMap.get("durtunit"));
System.out.println("query "+query);
bs.add(query);
count++;
}
session.executeAsync(bs);

session.close();
```

The `Map` `ColDataMap` has all the Cassandra Table col Names as key and their values In the map as shown below

```
{Seq_No=0, fileId=123, studyId=786, w=PreCLinic, x=Tasq 30mg/kg, y=12 days, z=12 days}
```

```
Set<String> colNamesSet =colDataMap.keySet();
String[] colNames = colNamesSet.toArray(new String[colNamesSet.size()]);
System.out.println("ColNames ::" +colNames);

String makeStatement =  makeSt(keyspace,tabName,colNames);

System.out.println("makeStatement ::"+makeStatement);
```

The method makeSt prepares the prepared Statement

```
makeStatement ::INSERT INTO orchtablespaces.EXPOSURES ( Seq_No,fileId,studyId,w,x,y,z ) values ( ?,?,?,?,?,?,? )
```

This is all fine. Then I do the following

```
PreparedStatement statement = session.prepare(makeStatement);
//bcz expoid and seq_no are of type bigint int the cassandra table
String expoid =(String) colDataMap.get("expoid");
String Seq_No = (String) colDataMap.get("Seq_No");
colDataMap.put(expoid, Long.valueOf(expoid));
colDataMap.put("Seq_No", Long.valueOf(Seq_No));

BoundStatement query = statement.bind(colDataMap.values().toArray(new Object[colDataMap.size()]));
```

When i run the program I am getting the following error

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException.copy(NoHostAvailableException.java:84)
com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.extractCauseFromExecutionException(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:289)com.test.load.microarr.CopyOfLoadMicroArr.transformSourceFile(CopyOfLoadMicroArr.java:486)com.test.load.microarr.CopyOfLoadMicroArr.loadData(CopyOfLoadMicroArr.java:149)
com.test.load.microarr.CopyOfLoadMicroArr.main(CopyOfLoadMicroArr.java:114)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (no host was tried)
com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.sendRequest(RequestHandler.java:107)
com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager.execute(SessionManager.java:538)
com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager.prepareAsync(SessionManager.java:124)
com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.prepare(AbstractSession.java:77)
    ... 3 more
com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.prepare(AbstractSession.java:79)
```

The exact line where the program is breaking is line 486 and that is at

```
 PreparedStatement statement = session.prepare(makeStatement);
```

I am using DataStax Cassandra 2.1.8 .. any suggestions and solutions would be really helpful !! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You definitely have problem with the connection to the cassandra.

Form the [Datastax Java driver documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.1/com/datastax/driver/core/Session.html#prepare-com.datastax.driver.core.RegularStatement-):

> NoHostAvailableException - if no host in the cluster can be contacted successfully to prepare this statement.

And form [the error description](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/exceptions/NoHostAvailableException.html)

> Exception thrown when a query cannot be performed because no host are
> available. This exception is thrown if
>
> - either there is no host live in
>   the cluster at the moment of the query
> - all host that have been tried
>   have failed due to a connection problem
>
> For debugging purpose, the
> list of hosts that have been tried along with the failure cause can be
> retrieved using the errors method.

Try to catch this error and output list of tried host - this could help you detect is there are wrong host or wrong port. Use `getErrors()` method - http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/exceptions/NoHostAvailableException.html#getErrors()

Comment: Hi, But when I tried another program with a simple insert statement to a table , it dint have any problems to insert nor of the connection , with the same configurations.

Comment: If you have no problem with a simple insert but have problem with the butch then I suppose you overload your nodes. You need to better tune cassandra (it could help but I am not sure what exactly must be tuned in your case), or add more nodes or decrease load on casandra - do less request. Try to do you batch statements from some low number -like 10 or so to verify this hypo.

Comment: Read the discussion under the approved answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27902232/cassandra-cluster-with-bad-insert-performance-and-insert-stability

Comment: How to use getErrors() on which object to call this method

Comment: NoHostAvailableException - look at this example: http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/2.1/java-driver/reference/exceptions_r.html