# error on cassandra with ~90k prepared statements to single partition with compound key

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver, spring-data-cassandra

I am doing synchronous inserts via prepared statements on cassandra, which causes my entire application to break down.
I write to one partition, about 90k different clustering entries in short time.

```
List<Statement> statements = new ArrayList<>();
map.forEach((String location, Set<String> set) -> {
    PreparedStatement updateStatement = preparedStatementSupplier.getUpdatePeriodByLocationStatement();
    BoundStatement boundStatement = updateStatement.bind(set, tradePartner, location);
    statements.add(boundStatement);
});

Iterator<Statement> iterator = statements.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Statement statement = iterator.next();
    try {
        cassandraOperations.execute(statement);
        iterator.remove();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        LOG.error("error on forecast data persistence, reason: {}", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}   

public synchronized PreparedStatement getUpdatePeriodByLocationStatement() {
    if (Objects.isNull(updatePeriodByLocation)) {
        // CREATE TABLE period_by_location (tp text, loc text, pd set<text>, PRIMARY KEY ((tp), loc));
        updatePeriodByLocation = cassandraOperations.getSession().prepare("UPDATE period_by_location SET pd = pd + ? WHERE tp = ? AND loc = ?");
        updatePeriodByLocation.setIdempotent(true);
    }
    return updatePeriodByLocation;
}
```

Which causes timeouts on the server side I guess and the driver to stop working. Cassandra runs more or less on default settings. The error on the cassandra nodes looks like this.

```
ERROR [SharedPool-Worker-3] 2017-11-29 15:41:37,084 ErrorMessage.java:338 - Unexpected exception during request
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.cassandra.serializers.UTF8Serializer$UTF8Validator.validate(UTF8Serializer.java:55) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at org.apache.cassandra.serializers.UTF8Serializer.validate(UTF8Serializer.java:34) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at org.apache.cassandra.serializers.SetSerializer.deserializeForNativeProtocol(SetSerializer.java:88) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.Sets$Value.fromSerialized(Sets.java:152) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.Sets$Marker.bind(Sets.java:251) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.Sets$Adder.execute(Sets.java:286) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.UpdateStatement.addUpdateForKey(UpdateStatement.java:112) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.UpdateStatement.addUpdateForKey(UpdateStatement.java:59) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.ModificationStatement.getMutations(ModificationStatement.java:744) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.ModificationStatement.executeWithoutCondition(ModificationStatement.java:531) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.ModificationStatement.execute(ModificationStatement.java:519) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.QueryProcessor.processStatement(QueryProcessor.java:226) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.QueryProcessor.processPrepared(QueryProcessor.java:492) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.QueryProcessor.processPrepared(QueryProcessor.java:469) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at org.apache.cassandra.transport.messages.ExecuteMessage.execute(ExecuteMessage.java:142) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at org.apache.cassandra.transport.Message$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Message.java:507) [apache-cassandra-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at org.apache.cassandra.transport.Message$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Message.java:401) [apache-cassandra-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105) [netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333) [netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$700(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:32) [netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$8.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:324) [netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService$FutureTask.run(AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:164) [apache-cassandra-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.SEPWorker.run(SEPWorker.java:105) [apache-cassandra-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]
```

What I read so far, is to slow down the rate of performing cassandrOperations.execute(). Is this the right way or is there any better solution. 
I greatly appreciate any tips.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`CassandrOperations.execute(…)` is the appropriate method. From your code, I'm wondering why you're using `CassandraOperations` at all as your code seems to be heavily optimized and `CassandraOperations` adds besides exception translation a bit of overhead.

Comment: I started the project with usage of CassandraOperations and still use it. But even with the overhead from spring, the statements are fired to fast. I read on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27902232/cassandra-cluster-with-bad-insert-performance-and-insert-stability) about semaphores and was wondering, if it is the right way to solve my problem?